# How to run a npm script on a deployed Heroku NodeJS app

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, heroku-toolbelt

Under `scripts` in `package.json` I have the following.

`'refresh': node refresh db`

Is there a way to trigger this particular npm script on a NodeJS app deployed on Heroku.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes:

```
$ heroku run npm run refresh
```

Comment: Sort of, but not quite - this will run in a one-off dyno, not on the same dyno(s) used to access the running app.

Comment: This answer is accurate. The question was not how to execute a script on a specific dyno, but how to execute one on a specific app. An app is made up of n ephemeral dynos on Heroku by design.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Heroku Node.js Documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#hook-things-up), you can add pre and post install scripts. In addition, you can add scripts that can be triggered by environment variables.

Comment: Yes, I have added a postinstall and start scripts but is there a way to trigger a npm script after the deploy is done? In my case I need to refresh the db on a need basis.

Comment: It would help if you could provide more details on what conditions will trigger this script.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using only the browser; Just log in to manage your app in the heroku dashboard (`https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/[app_name]`) and there click on the right side of it:
[More > Run console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Erwjr.png)

Then you can run any command:
[command line in heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USw97.png)

https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1137

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).