# Heroku Run Npm "Command Not Found"

Tags: node.js, meteor, heroku, npm

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38571318/8061904), when I try to run the suggested answer (heroku run npm run "script name") I get "bash: npm: command not found". I'm trying to trigger the script on a deployed meteor NodeJS app to Heroku (node version 4.8.2 and npm version 4.6.1). Any solutions to why?

**package.json**

```
{  
  "name": "admini_meteor",  
  "private": true,  
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "MONGO_URL=mongodb://52.1.130.211/cloud meteor"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

**Procfile**
`web: npm run deploy`

Comment: Can you post your code? (including Procfile and snippet from package.jsion)

Comment: Do you have npm installed?

Comment: @Lissy posted package.json and Procfile - essentially if I run locally with the command "npm run deploy" it will work as desired

Comment: You need a `start` script in your package.json

Comment: @MichelFloyd yes I do v4.6.1

Answer (score 3):

You need to add nodejs in your buildpack
[image]

And then deploy your app again! That's all!

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert but I will try to give you a hint of your problem because I had the same one. Everything is in the docs you just need to read it.
So far the [web](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#the-web-process-type) process in the one taking care of running the actual app/server like [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#define-a-procfile).
But also how is your project structure? Heroku detects you are developing a node project (because of package.json file in root directory) so it should install npm for you.

In my case I was developing a Laravel app, therefore, it created a PHP application without node and npm. There is a way to tell heroku you need both environments like state [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app)